# Pyqt5 QThread freezing and then exiting when thread starts

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, audio-streaming, qthread

I'm new to GUI-programming and need help with a QThread application.

I designed a GUI-Programm which records a Signal from the microphone and plots it in a Figure at the same time.
Now I want to evaluate the signal in another thread, so it still records and plots in the GUI.
The streaming and plotting works fine but everytime I start the thread the GUI freezes and then exits. 
Does somebody know what I did wrong in my code, I don't have that much Programming-experience?

```
# Imports ----------------------------
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.mlab import find
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):  # template for rest of GUI,
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1500, 900)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.channels = 2  # StereoSignal
        self.fs = 44100  # Samplingrate
        self.Chunks = 4096  # Buffersize
        self.streamstart = False
        self.audiodata = []  # to buffer streaming-values in

        self.tapeLength = 4  # seconds
        self.tape = np.empty(self.fs * self.tapeLength) * np.nan  # tape to store signal-chunks

        self.home()

    def home(self):
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Stream and Plot", self)  # Button to start streaming
        btn.clicked.connect(self.plot)
        btn.move(100, 100)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Stop", self)  # Button to stop streaming
        btn.clicked.connect(self.stop_signal)
        btn.move(200, 100)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Evaluate", self)  # Button for the Evaluation
        btn.clicked.connect(self.evaluation)
        btn.move(100, 140)

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)  # Show text of evaluation
        self.textEdit.move(250, 170)
        self.textEdit.resize(200, 200)

        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self)  # Scroll-Area to plot signal (Figure) in
        self.scrollArea.move(75, 400)
        self.scrollArea.resize(600, 300)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)

        self.figure = Figure((15, 2.8), dpi=100)  # figure instance (to plot on) F(width, height, ...)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.canvas)
        self.gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(self.gs[0])
        self.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.05)

    def start_stream(self, start=True):
        """start a Signal-Stream with pyAudio, with callback (to also play immediately)"""
        if start is True:
            self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
            self.stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32, channels=self.channels, rate=self.fs, input=True,
                                  output=True, frames_per_buffer=self.Chunks, stream_callback=self.callback)
            self.streamstart = True
            self.stream.start_stream()
            print("Recording...")

    def callback(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, flag):
        """Callback-Function which stores the streaming data in a list"""
        data = np.fromstring(np.array(in_data).flatten(), dtype=np.float32)
        self.audiodata = data
        print("appending...")
        return data, pyaudio.paContinue

    def tape_add(self):
        """add chunks from (callback)-list to tapes for left and right Signalparts"""
        if self.streamstart:
            self.tape[:-self.Chunks] = self.tape[self.Chunks:]
            self.taper = self.tape  # tape for right signal
            self.tapel = self.tape  # tape for left signal
            self.tapel[-self.Chunks:] = self.audiodata[::2]
            self.taper[-self.Chunks:] = self.audiodata[1::2]
            print("taping...")
        else:
            print("No streaming values found")

    def plot(self):
        """Start the streaming an plot the signal"""
        print("(Stereo-)Signal streaming & plotting...")

        if self.streamstart:
            pass
        else:
            self.start_stream(start=True)

        self.t1 = time.time()
        time.sleep(0.5)

        while self.streamstart:
            QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()  # does this still work with threads?
            print("Plotting...")
            self.tape_add()

            self.timeArray = np.arange(self.taper.size)
            self.timeArray = (self.timeArray / self.fs) * 1000  # scale to milliseconds

            self.ax.clear()
            self.ax.plot(self.timeArray, (self.taper / np.max(np.abs(self.taper))), '-b')
            self.ax.grid()
            self.ax.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
            self.ax.set_xlabel("Samples")
            self.canvas.draw()

    def stop_signal(self):
        print("Stopping Signal.")
        if self.streamstart:
            print("Stop Recording")
            self.stream.stop_stream()
            self.stream.close()
            self.p.terminate()
            self.streamstart = False
        else:
            pass

    def evaluation(self):
        """ Start the evaluation in another Thread"""
        threader = WorkerThread(self.taper, self.tapel)
        thread = QtCore.QThread()

        # threader.threadDone.connect(self.thread_done)  # doesn't work yet
        thread.started.connect(threader.run)
        thread.start()  # start thread


class WorkerThread(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self, taper, tapel):  # take the tape-parts from the original thread
        # super().__init__()  # do I need this or next?
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.__taper = taper
        self.__tapel = tapel

    def run(self):
        """Do evaluation, later mor, for now just some calculations"""
        print("Evaluating Signal")

        self.tpr = self.__taper.astype(np.float32, order='C') / 32768  # here the GUI freezes and then exits
        self.tpl = self.__tapel.astype(np.float32, order='C') / 32768
        # cut nan-values if there are some
        self.r = self.tpr[~np.isnan(self.tpr)]
        self.l = self.tpl[~np.isnan(self.tpl)]

        # normalize signals
        self.left2 = (self.l / np.max(np.abs(self.l)))
        self.right2 = (self.r / np.max(np.abs(self.r)))
        self.norm_audio2 = np.array((self.left2, self.right2))  # like channels (in de_interlace)

        # do some calculations

        self.databew = """ Mute, Loudness and PSNR/MOS...
                      Dominant fundamental frequencies etc.
                    """
        print(self.databew)
        # self.textEdit.append(self.databew)  # would this work?
        # self.threadDone.emit('Thread-Bewertung Done.')  # later implemented


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    GUI.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


main()
```

So the streaming parts work, maybe someone can tell me what's wrong with the Threading-Part, where I want to do some simple calculations with the recorded signal?
The thread doesn't work with the Signal still recording, but also not, when I stop the recording and plotting and have the Signal in a buffer.
I'm sorry I couldn't get a simpler programm working with similar values, where the same problem occurs.

Hope someone can still help me?

thx, Julia

Comment: The Probelm might be the QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents() in the main-Part, but if I don't have it, the GUI already freezes from just recording and plotting. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little trying out different things I found a sulition. So the Problem was indeed the QApplication.ProcessEvents-part. This is for completing loops in PyQt, but mine is a endless loop, only stopped after a button-klick. This is why the GUI froze everytime I used it.

The solution now, was to put the plotting part also in a new Thread, which can access the GUI-window.

Here is the new code, which works fine and reasonable fast:

```
# Imports ----------------------------
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):  # template for rest of GUI,
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1500, 900)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.channels = 2  # StereoSignal
        self.fs = 44100  # Samplingrate
        self.Chunks = 4096  # Buffersize
        self.streamstart = False
        self.audiodata = []  # to buffer streaming-values in

        self.tapeLength = 4  # seconds
        self.tape = np.empty(self.fs * self.tapeLength) * np.nan  # tape to store signal-chunks

        self.home()

    def home(self):
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Stream and Plot", self)  # Button to start streaming
        btn.clicked.connect(self.plot)
        btn.move(100, 100)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Stop", self)  # Button to stop streaming
        btn.clicked.connect(self.stop_signal)
        btn.move(200, 100)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Evaluate", self)  # Button for the Evaluation
        btn.clicked.connect(self.evaluation)
        btn.move(100, 140)

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)  # Show text of evaluation
        self.textEdit.move(250, 170)
        self.textEdit.resize(200, 200)

        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self)  # Scroll-Area to plot signal (Figure) in
        self.scrollArea.move(75, 400)
        self.scrollArea.resize(600, 300)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)

        self.figure = Figure((15, 2.8), dpi=100)  # figure instance (to plot on) F(width, height, ...)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.canvas)
        self.gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(self.gs[0])
        self.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.05)

    def start_stream(self, start=True):
        """start a Signal-Stream with pyAudio, with callback (to also play immediately)"""
        if start is True:
            self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
            self.stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32, channels=self.channels, rate=self.fs, input=True,
                                  output=True, frames_per_buffer=self.Chunks, stream_callback=self.callback)
            self.streamstart = True
            self.stream.start_stream()
            print("Recording...")

    def callback(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, flag):
        """Callback-Function which stores the streaming data in a list"""
        data = np.fromstring(np.array(in_data).flatten(), dtype=np.float32)
        self.audiodata = data
        print("appending...")
        return data, pyaudio.paContinue

    def tape_add(self):
        """add chunks from (callback)-list to tapes for left and right Signalparts"""
        if self.streamstart:
            self.tape[:-self.Chunks] = self.tape[self.Chunks:]
            self.taper = self.tape  # tape for right signal
            self.tapel = self.tape  # tape for left signal
            self.tapel[-self.Chunks:] = self.audiodata[::2]
            self.taper[-self.Chunks:] = self.audiodata[1::2]
            print("taping...")
        else:
            print("No streaming values found")

    def plot(self):
        """Start the streaming an plot the signal"""
        print("(Stereo-)Signal streaming & plotting...")

        self.plot_thread = PlotThead(self)
        self.plot_thread.start()

    def stop_signal(self):
        print("Stopping Signal.")
        if self.streamstart:
            print("Stop Recording")
            self.stream.stop_stream()
            self.stream.close()
            self.p.terminate()
            self.streamstart = False
            self.plot_thread.stop()
        else:
            pass

    def evaluation(self):
        """ Start the evaluation in another Thread"""
        self.thread = WorkerThread(self, self.taper, self.tapel)

        self.thread.start()  # start thread


class PlotThead(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, window):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.deamon = True
        self.__is_running = True
        self.window = window

    def stop(self):
        self.__is_running = False

    def run(self):

        if self.window.streamstart:
            pass
        else:
            self.window.start_stream(start=True)

        self.window.t1 = time.time()
        time.sleep(0.5)

        while self.window.streamstart and self.__is_running:
            print("Plotting...")
            self.window.tape_add()

            self.window.timeArray = np.arange(self.window.taper.size)
            self.window.timeArray = (self.window.timeArray / self.window.fs) * 1000  # scale to milliseconds

            self.window.ax.clear()
            self.window.ax.plot(self.window.timeArray, (self.window.taper / np.max(np.abs(self.window.taper))), '-b')
            self.window.ax.grid()
            self.window.ax.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
            self.window.ax.set_xlabel("Samples")
            self.window.canvas.draw()


class WorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, window, taper, tapel):  # take the tape-parts from the original thread
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.__taper = taper
        self.__tapel = tapel
        self.deamon = True
        self.window = window

    def run(self):
        """Do evaluation, later mor, for now just some calculations"""
        print("Evaluating Signal")

        self.tpr = self.__taper.astype(np.float32, order='C') / 32768  # here the GUI freezes and then exits
        self.tpl = self.__tapel.astype(np.float32, order='C') / 32768
        # cut nan-values if there are some
        self.r = self.tpr[~np.isnan(self.tpr)]
        self.l = self.tpl[~np.isnan(self.tpl)]

        # normalize signals
        self.left2 = (self.l / np.max(np.abs(self.l)))
        self.right2 = (self.r / np.max(np.abs(self.r)))
        self.norm_audio2 = np.array((self.left2, self.right2))  # like channels (in de_interlace)

        # do some calculations

        self.databew = """ Mute, Loudness and PSNR/MOS...
                  Dominant fundamental frequencies etc.
                """
        print(self.databew)
        self.window.textEdit.append(self.databew)  # would this work?


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    GUI.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


main()
```